# JTextField, check field

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

My intent is programming a java applet form, whit connection in a database. 
when the user compile field, how can check the input while compile and show if exist in a database?

example: 
Username: myuser. near the jtextfield a label status notify if the test exist in the database. the control need check when the user have finish compile field and not when click on the button. how a control strenght of password.
its possibile?

Comment: Mostly people would achieve that by writing code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do some research, write some code, and if you have a specific question or problem with your code, post it here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

You can control the weight of the password by using `JPassword` class, and making a boolean method that validates the password length doesn't exceed a certain length. For example:

```
public boolean checkPassword()
{
    private JPassword password;

    if (password.length >= 20) // checking if the password is greater or equal 20
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException;
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else
        return password;
}
```

Comment: What is a `JPassword` class? Do you mean `JPasswordField`? If yes, this class has no accessable `length` field. `throw new IllegalArgumentException;` is also not correct.

Comment: this method dont perform my intent, i need update a JLabel when insert the password, maybe the keyup event?